# How likely is it to get killed by a hopping side kick?

Tags: kicking, injury, jump-kick

Something like 12 years ago I participated in tournaments for fighting. After many years I learned that one can get killed by getting hit in the liver area and so on... I don't know if this depression or overthinking thing has ever made you suffer or not so I want to know if my hopping side kicks to the opponents has done them damage. I was 57 kilogram and highly trained with great flexibility. In one occasion I knocked down a karate artist who had a black belt by kicking around right part of belly and the other time I threw a hopping side kick to my opponent but he wasn't knocked down and he decided not to continue the fight after it.

Comment: Yeah, as Tony's answer mentioned, if they got up and seemed fine, then they were fine. There's no long-term damage you have to worry about. If you managed to really damage someone's liver, they would be heading to the hospital. They wouldn't even be able to move. Most of the long-term damage you should worry about in martial arts practice is damage to the brain. But that's a different subject.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You helped so much

Comment: @HamidrezaDehanvi I write this with the sole intention of possibly helping you. I assure you I have no other intent and I write this with zero judgement or any type of negativity.  Your question makes me wonder if you are suffering from Obsessive Compulsive Disorder (OCD).  OCD can generate pervasive fears that the afflicted has harmed others.  Psychiatric (medication) and psychological (therapy) treatments are available to help those suffering from OCD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of people fight full contact (muay thai, kickboxing, and full-contact karate systems like kyokushin) for years and take blows like this regularly - if the guys got up at the time and seemed ok, the chances that your blows had any significant long-term effect is incredibly small.  That one of the guys was still standing suggests you didn't get a particularly solid liver shot in that time anyway.  How badly they'll have been effected depends a lot on whether the attack caught them unprepared - with muscles relaxed, especially when inhaling - the attack can more easily penetrate to compress the liver.  You were light weight, and - no offence intended but in my experience - that you mentioned flexibility as if it was of any real significance suggests you don't understand body mechanics terribly well, which means you've probably never employed them terribly well, so just more reasons to think the strike was unlikely to have had a lasting effect.

Comment: Thank you for your time. You answered my question and help me a lot.

Comment: If the victim had unusually thick blood, couldn't a blow like this cause a blood clot that might later dislodge and cause a heart attack or stroke?

Comment: @nick012000: I'm not a doctor, so I can't speculate on how likely that is - but of course if you reframe the question in terms of _"if they were just about to die, could this be the straw that broke the camel's back"_ then the answer is generally yes, however minor the "straw" is.  That said, these people were martial artists fit enough to want to fight in a tournament; the one who was "knocked down" was apparently a black belt in karate - his usual training probably kept him in reasonable health....